# How to write implement to override interface in java?

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am working on a java solution that uses the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) maven pkg to generate code for the OAS3 API that I need to implement/use.  I am trying to get at the header information on successful call back.  There is a generated interface called ApiCallback that has method signature `void onSuccess(T result, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders)`. While the model has response type, how to also retrieve specific header info?

This question will likely need some development, so please make a comment below with request for more detail.  Thanks

Comment: I'd guess this comes in the `responseHeaders`

Comment: Yes.  I am new to java (coming from c#) and trying to figure out how to implement this interface.  It gets generated, and I am unsure where/how to implement in order to capture the key/values of interest from the responseHeaders.

Comment: What is the generatorName you are using as different generators will generate different java code

Comment: The key discovery here was to use the method suffixed with "WithHttpInfo", which returns the generic type of `ApiResponse`. I make a new type to handle the header info that can be get with method `getHeaders`.